# Rails validation - password :on => :create doesn't works?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, validation, passwords

I have this rule for password validation - I wanna validate the password when a user creates an account and then in settings - if he doesn't change the password, I don't want to change it (only when the respective user will change it = he set up the new password with password confirmation).

Here is what I have:

```
  validates :password, 
            :length => {:within => 6..40}, 
            :on => :create
```

But the rule `:on => :create` doesn't work for me - if I send blank password in settings, I am still getting error about incorrect password.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: That's email validation, what is your password validation?

Comment: Oh sorry, my mistake, please see the updated OP.

Answer (score 0):

looks like this should do:

```
validates :password, length: { within: (6..40) }, if: -> user { not user.persisted? or user.password.present? }
```

it will only validate password if user is not yet persisted(`create` action) or password has been provided later(through settings)